# How to detect whether a string is in URL format using javascript?

Tags: javascript, url

I think the question title seems to explain eveything.
I want to detect whether a string is in URL format or not using javascript.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try this-

```
function isUrl(s) {
   var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
   return regexp.test(s);
}
```

> usage: if (isUrl("http://www.page.com")) alert("is correct") else
>   alert("not correct");

Comment: Hi @MarkRedman, the resource on snippets.dzone that you have linked to seems to have been moved ( I get a 410 Gone error message). Is there an updated version of it? Thanks!

Comment: Take note that `s` must be in lowercase.

Answer (score 12):

```
function IsURL(url) {

    var strRegex = "^((https|http|ftp|rtsp|mms)?://)"
        + "?(([0-9a-z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+: )?[0-9a-z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+@)?" //ftp的user@
        + "(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" // IP形式的URL- 199.194.52.184
        + "|" // 允许IP和DOMAIN（域名）
        + "([0-9a-z_!~*'()-]+\.)*" // 域名- www.
        + "([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]{0,61})?[0-9a-z]\." // 二级域名
        + "[a-z]{2,6})" // first level domain- .com or .museum
        + "(:[0-9]{1,4})?" // 端口- :80
        + "((/?)|" // a slash isn't required if there is no file name
        + "(/[0-9a-z_!~*'().;?:@&=+$,%#-]+)+/?)$";
     var re=new RegExp(strRegex);
     return re.test(url);
 }
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo (Improved version which matches also 'localhost')](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KaJrYj7vm9pKgOhK)

Comment: This was the best one I found so far. The only thing, it returns true to isURL("http").

Comment: very nice. 'https|http|ftp...' can written shorter => 'https?|ftp...'

Comment: Improved version to match even 'localhost': add '|localhost' after `+ "[a-z]{2,6})" // first level domain- .com or .museum` inside the bracket => `+ "[a-z]{2,6}|localhost)" // first level domain- .com or .museum`

Comment: IsURL('11/01/2020') --> true

Comment: any string at least 4 characters return `true`

Comment: it is not accurate any string let say
console.log(IsURL("rama"));
it returns true.

Answer (score 9):

try something like this:

```
function isUrl(s) {
    var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)? (\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
    return regexp.test(s);
}
```

Comment: isUrl() function does not work for
"http://localhost/myprojects",
"http://127.0.0.1/myprojects"

Answer (score 8):

One for the future using the [URL constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) and a basic try catch statement, it is supported in most modern browsers. Obviously no IE support...

```
const isUrl = (str) => {
  try {
    new URL(str);
    return true;
  } catch () {
    return false;  
  }
}
```

If the URL is valid it will get parsed by the constructor and return true.

If the string is not a valid URL the constructor will chuck a syntax error that will get caught and return false.

Comment: Note that this will technically pass as valid with the URL constructor: `http://www.`

Answer (score 4):

Try this code. This expression is more complete and takes into account IP address:

```
function checkUrl(s) {
     var regexp = /^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/
     return regexp.test(s); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression for checking the string

```
^s?https?:\/\/[-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z0-9;\/?:\@&=+\$,%#]+$
```

[Regular Expressions and Javascript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same task, but all of regex that I found online to check validity of a URL were failed in some test cases.

Here is the regex that worked everything:

```
/^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|www\.)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?/
```

However, If the URL was like: **google.com** It accepted it as valid (which in my specific case, was considered as **invalid**)

It worked the best I had found. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

When given the option, I prefer the simplest solution.

Use `_.startsWith(string, 'http')` if:

- You don't mind if URL is invalid
- You're sure the URL being checked will always start with 'http'
- You don't expect the string to be another value that might start also with 'http'