# HTML script injection via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text field where user can fill href tag script which I have to show as a link later on. But your can enter some malicious script like alert message and more like that which will cause execution on unwanted script at the point where I use that text field value to display.
My question is that how can I restrict user to only enter href tag releated entry in text field and restrict other script to enter.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: be more specific Show your code.

Comment: Add server side validation

Comment: This SO answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: regular expressions can solve your problem.
this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation

Comment: I have used $(variable_name).text of jquery it is working fine in all browsers giving me plain text removing html tags but not working in IE 8. In IE-8 it is giving empty string for "<script>for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) alert('Hello!!'); </script>" string but working fine for "<p>for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) alert('Hello!!'); </p>" script. means <script> related tags are not processed by $(variable_name).text() of jquery in IE 8. Any suggestion for IE8 plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use regular expression

```
var urlmatch= /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/;
var textboxValue = textbox.value;
if(textboxValue.match(urlmatch)){
// return true
} else {

// return false;
}
```

Comment: this is very fine regex pattern but one more issue is there I have to accept simple string also with href string and this expression is ignoring simple string :(

Comment: That is I want only two things either href contained script or any string that is not a HTML malicious script :(

Comment: so when it doesnt match to regexp which in your case will be script it will return false...

Comment: Thanks CodeJack I have used your regex and $(variable_name).text() concept to prevent execution on script injected and also make hyperlink to show as it is as per your regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

Comment: but what will be the case is only simple string is passed. I have to receive either a HREF contained script or a simple string (combination of any characters, alphabets, symbols but not a html script).

Answer (score 0):

U need to check whether string is url , if its url accept else reject .. the below links will help ur cause.                                   [How to detect whether a string is in URL format using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701898/how-to-detect-whether-a-string-is-in-url-format-using-javascript)                                       [check if string contains url anywhere in string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570286/check-if-string-contains-url-anywhere-in-string-using-javascript)