# Website validation in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a field that accepts a URL. How do I validate this URL in angularjs.

```
<div class="controls">
   <input type="text" ng-model="controller.data.PropertyWebsite"/>
</div>
```

Any ideas and suggestions are appreciated !!!!

Comment: Please define what exactly you mean by *validate*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701898/how-to-detect-whether-a-string-is-in-url-format-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a html input[url] to a form and mark it as required, then use angular to check if the form is valid or not:

**html:**

```
<form name="form">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="url" name="url" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button type="submit" ng-click="SubmitForm('form')">submit</button>                                    </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.submitForm = function () {

    if (this.form.$invalid)
        //not valid
    } else {
        //valid
    }
}
```

More information about url input:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Burl%5D

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-pattern to validate against a RegEx. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input